# Card view is displaying on other fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `CardView` setup at the main screen (with `RecyclerView`). So when I try to go through my `NavigationDrawer` and switch to different `Fragment`, `CardView` gets displayed above it (and yes I have used recycler view
Can anybody help?

Item layout containing card view added (xDDD more details)

Activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.wallpaperstore.thelastofuswallpapersandwalkthrough.MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/flcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


</FrameLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Navigation_v"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"

    android:layout_gravity="start" >
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_walkthrough.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.wallpaperstore.thelastofuswallpapersandwalkthrough.Walkthrough">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Item layout

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
app:cardElevation="10dp">

<com.battleent.ribbonviews.RibbonLayout
    android:id="@+id/ribbonLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    app:bottom_ribbonColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:bottom_textColor="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


    <Button
         android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Set Wallpaper"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
        tools:text="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" />


 </com.battleent.ribbonviews.RibbonLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Does your code really work? Drawer layout accepts only two children and you have added three children to the drawer layout. see the documentation. https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: What to do now?

Comment: I don't want card view to appear on walkthrough fragment

Comment: where you want to display recycler view??

Comment: On the main activity (the starting scrren when the app starts)

Comment: I have made another xml file for cardview

Comment: Add recycler view in a different fragment and oncreate activity add the fragment to the frame layout. When the click happens from the navigation drawer simply replace the old fragment with the new one.

Comment: Can yous send me a proper code

Comment: I don't think so that this empty frame layout container tag you put is appropriate. well any ways one simple solution that you can put is when any fragment gets its commit you can use yourView.SetVisibilty() = View.GONE on your FrameLayout conatainer or that mystery cardView which is not shown in the snippet you gave us in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(container, newFragment).commit();
```

instead of adding fragment